# Displaying each two array items in one loop item with right placement

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, for-loop, math

I am trying to do something fit with the design, so i have to show 2 item in 1 loop. Also, according to this design, should be line break in each 4 loop. Line breaks applying automatically, but its fixed 4. So, in 4 loop it shows actually 8 items. However, the point I'm stuck on is; items are not displaying in the placement I want. You can see the placement I want to do with more detail in the picture.

- Red Numbers = **Current placement**
- Green Numbers = **Placement it should be**
- Yellow boxes  = **For loop items** ( 8 items )
- Black boxes = **Items in array** (16 items )

[image: See the picture].

```css
ul,li {
padding:0;
margin:0;
list-style:none;
}

li {
width:30px;
}
.gen {
  width: 140px
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.ic {
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<ul class="gen">
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li class="ic">a</li>
      <li class="ic">b</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li class="ic">c</li>
      <li class="ic">d</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li class="ic">e</li>
      <li class="ic">f</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li class="ic">g</li>
      <li class="ic">h</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li class="ic">i</li>
      <li class="ic">j</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li class="ic">k</li>
      <li class="ic">l</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li class="ic">m</li>
      <li class="ic">n</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li class="ic">o</li>
      <li class="ic">p</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**As you can see, items are not placing alphabetically from left to right.**

Here is the loop i used :

```
// 16 items
$items = array('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p'); 
$half = count($items) / 2;
$k = 0;

echo '<ul class="gen">';
for($i = 0; $i<$half; $i++) {
  echo '<li>';
  echo '<ul>';
  echo '<li class="ic">'.$items[$k].'</li>';
  echo '<li class="ic">'.$items[$k+1].'</li>';
  echo '</ul>';
  echo '</li>';
  $k = $k+2;
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: why do you divide array to 2 parts but not 4 ?

Comment: Because there is has to be 2 item in 1 section. You can see clearly in [this picture](https://prnt.sc/h6adkw) Really hard to tell. Also my english is not that good.

Comment: your code only will output "abcdefgh...p" not even red numbers, how do you format your output?

Comment: code snippet added please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this helps. You can run this code and see the output.

```
// chaganged the array to match your picture.
$items = array('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16');
//used to format the output
echo "<pre>";
for ( $i = 0; $i<count($items) ; $i++ ) {
    echo "loop start \n";
    // access 1st item
    echo $items[$i]."\n";
    // based on your example, it seems that you need the item that is 4 places after the first item of the loop
    echo $items[$i+4]."\n";
    echo "loop end\n";
    // we can use mod to check if we have reached the 4th element (index 3), we use $i+1 to check the second element of the loop
    if ( ( $i+1 )%4 == 0 ) {
        echo "\n---new line---\n";
        $i = $i + 4;
    }
    echo "\n";
}
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you will take care of the formatting, your code could be changed to this:

```
$items = array('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p'); 

for($first = 0; $first < count($items); $first += 8) {
    for($add = 0; $add < 4; $add++) {
        echo $items[$first + $add]; //first item
        echo $items[$first + $add + 4]; //second item
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May I see your HTML code? Here's a suggestion, display your results like this (run code snippet and use my css and php loop);

```css
#wrapper{
 background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
 padding:10px;
}

.result{
 display:inline-block;
 padding:7px;
 border:3px solid #FEBF01;
 width:120px;
}

.result-child{
 display:block;
 padding:10px 10px;
 background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
 color:rgba(50,255,100,1);
 font-size:2em;
 text-align:right;
}

.result .result-child:first-of-type{
 margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
 <div class="result">
  <div class="result-child">1</div>
  <div class="result-child">1</div>
 </div>

 <div class="result">
  <div class="result-child">2</div>
  <div class="result-child">2</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Loop code:

```
for($i = 0; $i<$half; $i++) {
  echo "<div class='result'>";
  echo "<div class='result-child'>".$items[$k]."</div>"; //first item
  echo "<div class='result-child'>".$items[$k+1]."</div>"; //second item
  echo "</div>";
  $k = $k+2;
}
```

Comment: Code snippet added please check.

Comment: Use div nested elements instead of ul and li nested. Div offers more customizability when it comes to styling.